# Curl uncorrect body

Tags: curl, postman

The issue is in parsing the body in the curl command

I used the web app to perform the post request and it was succesfully, and I got the curl command of the post as follows `curl -k -u "redacted:redacted"  --ntlm  "https://redacted/certsrv/certfnsh.asp" --header "Mode: newreq"  --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  --data-urlencode "Mode=newreq"  --data-urlencode "CertRequest=-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----redacted-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----"  --data-urlencode "CertAttrib=CertificateTemplate:CertificatElasticSearch"  --data-urlencode "FriendlyType=Saved-Request Certificate"  --data-urlencode "TargetStoreFlags=0"  --data-urlencode "SaveCert=yes"` and this works just fine but when i want another CertAttrib as here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYsoN.png) the curl command didn't work, so how can I have `CertAttrib: CertificateTemplate:Copie du modèle « Serveur Web »` as body I believe the issue is in the special characters, even trying with postman didn't work, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDVTy.png) this works but changing it to the desired CertAttrib didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create multipart request where as generated curl is not using multipart form.
use following example

```
curl -X POST --url https://httpbin.org/post \
   --form Mode=newreq \
   --form 'CertRequest=-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----redacted--- END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----' \
   --form 'CertAttrib=<attributes>'
```

Writing curl request is little hard. You can use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShivaPrasanth.dothttp-code&ssr=false

for making multipart request with ease via following code.

Below is easy to read.

```http
POST "https://httpbin.org/post"
files(
    
    ("Mode", "newreq"),
    ("CertRequest", "-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----redacted--- END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----"),
    ("CertAttrib", "<attributes>")

)
```